# Why does import a.b.c run __init.py__ while from a.b.c import does not?

Tags: python, package, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

Consider this simple Python package structure (where each `__init__.py` just prints the containing directory name and `test.py` prints `'test'`):

```
a
├── __init__.py
└── b
    ├── __init__.py
    └── c
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test.py
```

Now if I import `test` two different ways I get completely different results:

```
>>> import a.b.c.test
a
b
c
test
>>> from a.b.c import test
>>>
```

Why are `__init__.py` files not run in the second case? Where is this documented?

Comment: It's because modules are cached in `sys.modules` so they are only imported once per session.